# compare modelsim simulation result with a theory text file using vhdl

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I would like to compare a modelsim stimuli with a math theory function

for that I must export my simulation data from modelsim to .lst file and then create vhdl program who read the .lst file and compare it with math.do file which contain a integer input value

I'm trying to make a list but I don't got what I want
[the file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdY4U.png)

if this is the list, what mean the second column?

I don't know how to export data from modelsim ?
the second question is: is this method that I'll do is right or I must do something else?

please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

### First QA:

A "Delta delay" is an infinitesimal delay (= ~0 s delay). It is used to evaluate sequential events within a time-step. E.g. combinatorial statements:

```
a <= not b;
b <= '1';
```

Is equivalent to

```
process
begin
    a <= not b;
    wait until b'event;
end process;
process
begin
    b <= '1';
    wait;
end process;
```

Thus after `b <= '1'` at delta cycle 1 the first process will be triggered again and `a <= not '1';` will be evaluated at delta cycle 2.

---

### Second QA

Google on "vhdl file io": [example](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-file-io.html)